# Perl unzip / dynamic naming and error handling

Tags: perl, unzip

I ran into a bit of a snag recently with a long running (and working) script and have come to the conclusion that there needs to be a better approach to this problem.

Once a day a file is emailed to a generic account.  Postfix hands it off to this script for processing, essentially it just looks for any file attachments and saves them off.  99.9% of the time there's just 1 attachment, a zip file, and it's sent with a .DOC extension to get it through the spam filter.

Sometimes, however, the file is sent as 'file.DOC' other times 'file.doc' and still others 'file.doc.zip' or 'file.DOC.zip'  In each case there's only 1 file attached, but in order to handle these scenarios my script looks like this:

```
if ( </tmp/*.doc> ){
        unzip '</tmp/*.doc>' => '</media/win/#1.txt>'
                or die "unzip failed: $UnzipError\n";
}

if ( </tmp/*.DOC> ){
        unzip '</tmp/*.DOC>' => '</media/win/#1.txt>'
            or die "unzip failed: $UnzipError\n";
}
```

Is there a better way to handle these possible conditions with the filenaming that I can't control? It could be .zip, .ZIP, .DOC, .doc, or whatever else the human decides to type that day despite clear instructions.  (Isn't that always the case?"  I know generally how large the file will be - could I unzip based on that, or find some other non-filename way to do it?

Comment: When the casing can vary, I usually reach for `lc` and compare that.

Answer (score 0):

You can grep all the files with with .doc and .zip extensions ignoring the case and do what you need to do with them:

```
opendir(DIR, '/tmp/');
my @files = grep {/\.(doc|zip)$/i} readdir(DIR);
closedir DIR;

foreach my $file (@files) {
    #do what you need to do with each file
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest avoiding filenames -- you're looking for zip files, so use that as your filter:

```
use File::Type;
my $ft = File::Type->new();

opendir(DIR, '/tmp/');
my @files = grep { $ft->mime_type( $_ ) =~ qr"application/zip" } readdir(DIR);
closedir DIR;

foreach my $file (@files) {
    #do what you need to do with each file
}
```